# PHP Switch from loop

Tags: php, while-loop, switch-statement

Im looping through a database from a Query. This loop displays a list of Object Names and sets the Object Value as the Radio Value.

What I have is a table. It should display the reset of the query information once the radio button is clicked. The Objects are roughly around 1,100 objects and are constantly changing.

I am unsure how to get the Value of the selected radio button and assign it to a variable named "$ObjIndex" , the $ObjIndex will define how the $myQ9 will run
NOTE: It works fine if I put $ObjIndex = '1407'; (Which is one of the Object Index value.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="myform" actiopn="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="get">  
<?php 
$myQ1 = mysql_query("SELECT `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileIndex`, `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileName`, `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectIndex`, `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectName`, `iDocuments`.`Version`.`Version`, `iDocuments`.`File`.`UploadDate` FROM `iDocuments`.`Version` INNER JOIN `iDocuments`.`Object` ON `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectIndex` = `iDocuments`.`Version`.`ObjectIndex` JOIN `iDocuments`.`File` ON `iDocuments`.`Version`.`FileIndex` = `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileIndex` WHERE `Object`.`ObjectStatus` = '1' AND `Version`.`Version` = ( SELECT MAX(`Version`) FROM `iDocuments`.`Version` WHERE `Version`.`ObjectIndex` = `Object`.`ObjectIndex` ) ORDER BY `Object`.`ObjectName` ASC");
if (!$myQ1) 
   {  
      echo 'Could not run query 1: ' . mysql_error(); 
   } 
else 
   { 
  $row1 = mysql_query($myQ1);

while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($myQ1) ) 
{
 echo "<td><input type='radio' name='tog' id='tog' onClick='gtdoc()'  value='$row1[2]'>$row1[3]</input></td></tr>";
}

$myQ9 = mysql_query("SELECT `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileIndex`,   `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileName`, `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectIndex`, `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectName`, `iDocuments`.`Version`.`Version`, `iDocuments`.`File`.`UploadDate` FROM `iDocuments`.`Version` INNER JOIN `iDocuments`.`Object` ON `iDocuments`.`Object`.`ObjectIndex` = `iDocuments`.`Version`.`ObjectIndex` JOIN `iDocuments`.`File` ON `iDocuments`.`Version`.`FileIndex` = `iDocuments`.`File`.`FileIndex` WHERE `Object`.`ObjectStatus` = '1' AND `Version`.`Version` = ( SELECT MAX(`Version`) FROM `iDocuments`.`Version` WHERE `Version`.`ObjectIndex` = `Object`.`ObjectIndex` ) AND `Object`.`ObjectIndex` = '$ObjIndex'");
if (!$myQ9) 
   {  
      echo 'Could not run query 9: ' . mysql_error(); 
   }
else 
   { 
      $row9 = mysql_query($myQ9);

while( $row9 = mysql_fetch_array($myQ9) ) 
   {
      echo "<table name='doclist'>           
  <tr><td>FileID</td><td><input name='DocFileID' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[0]'></input></td></tr> 
  <tr><td>File Name</td><td><input name='DocFileName' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[1]'></input></td></tr> 
  <tr><td>ObjectID</td><td><input name='DocID' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[2]'></input></td></tr>  
  <tr><td>Object Name</td><td><input name='DocName' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[3]'></input></td></tr>  
  <tr><td>Current Version</td><td><input name='CurrVer' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[4]'></input></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Update Date</td><td><input name='lstupdate' type='text' readonly='true' value='$row9[5]'></input></td> </tr>
  </table>";
 }
} ?>
</form>
```

Comment: What question do you have? I see you are errantly calling `mysql_query()` again on `$myQ9` which is a result resource from your first call to `mysql_query()`\

Comment: I think you need to separate out the table tags from your while statement..and then iterate over the data under tr and td tags

Comment: The first query is searching the database to display the table the second should search the database based on the selected radio button. I dont know how to get the selected radio button

Comment: I am unsure how to get the Value of the selected radio button and assign it to a variable named "$ObjIndex" , the $ObjIndex will define how the $myQ9 will run NOTE: It works fine if I put $ObjIndex = '1407'; (Which is one of the Object Index value.

Comment: Well, if you have a radio button on a PREVIOUS page, you can access it via `$_POST['nameofradiobutton']` or `$_GET['nameofradionbutton']` depending on how you submitted the Form

Comment: Right now its all on the same page, should it be on different pages?